# How to use jest on karma?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jestjs

I want to use jest framework. So in karma.conf file i have included jest in the framework field. But it is giving error "WARN [reporter]: Can not load "jest", it is not registered!" when i run karma start. I have included the jest package( "jest": "~0.1.39", "jest-cli": "~0.4.1") in the dependencies of package.json file.

Can someone give me some example for using jest in karma?

Answer (score 1):

According this issue https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/139 it is not trivial to run jest in real browser.